# How do I backup and restore C drive of Windows 10, from Linux?

Tags: linux, open-source, backup

Is there a way to snapshot a Windows C-drive, within Linux. It's a dual boot system (Linux is on USB and Win10 is on hard disk). I don't want to use a commercial tool like *Paragon*. Could I also save the partition table and restore it from within Linux. What about the win10 500MB partition? I'd like to compress the stored image/filesystem.

I know *dd* can do this, but *dd* is slow and works with the entire partition. Are there any other tools? Someone on IRC suggested *rsync* - what options would I use to backup the HAL/SAM etc?

Answer (score 1):

I used Clonezilla and Partimag for that exact purpose (they are based on one another, I guess, so, basically, the same thing?) Can backup/restore separate partitions or the entire drive, partition table included. Can compress the backup files, too.